# how to apply tag functionality on drupal 7 nodes?

Tags: views

I want to show tag in my news content type and want to show these tag for specific node in front end with the help of views.

Comment: You've pretty much described what Drupal + views does out of the box. What's your specific question? Where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add a term reference field to the content type, and choose your vocabulary.

See the below screenshot of a view to see how to show tags for nodes in a view.

[image]

Comment: yes.. i did this.. but I want to show this term(with assigned node) where i am displaying nodes via view .

Comment: @jsh I edited my answer.

Comment: Can I use cloudtag functionality in drupal 7

Comment: Yes you can, There is a Module for That™ You want [this module](https://www.drupal.org/project/tagclouds)

Comment: I have 2 vocabulary on my content type.. but from view I need to show only one vocabulary term.. is it possible?

Comment: You can limit the vocabulary I think